# Create an azure policy to block role assignments to certain principal types, except when created by specified users

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have a requirement that subscription owners may only create role assignments for applications, not for users and groups. There should be an exception for certain identities that are be allowed to create role assignments for users and groups.

The policy below works, for existing role assignments. Existing role assignments to groups/users created by the specified IDs are compliant. Existing role assignments to users/groups created by other principals are not compliant. Great!

But when one of the specified IDs creates a new role assignment, it is denied.

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "eslz-restrict role assigments",
        "description": "Restrict role assignments to SPNs only, except when granted by specified ids",
        "mode": "All",
        "metadata": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "category": "RoleAssignments"
        },
        "parameters": {},
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
                    },
                    {
                        "anyOf": [
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/principalType",
                                "equals": "User"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/principalType",
                                "equals": "Group"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "anyOf": [
                            {
                                "not": {
                                    "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/createdBy",
                                    "in": [
                                        "bcd054a8-7cbf-4317-a673-93d32b7e296a",
                                        "13f29b01-7105-4f63-bd56-259ce07df96d"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "not": {
                                    "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/updatedBy",
                                    "in": [
                                        "bcd054a8-7cbf-4317-a673-93d32b7e296a",
                                        "13f29b01-7105-4f63-bd56-259ce07df96d"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "deny"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/createdBy` and `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/updatedBy` aren't available for you in this scenario, it's simply too soon to lookup these kind of values about an object that isn't created yet. You can see for yourself by calling `az role assignment create --assignee objectName --role Contributor --scope /subscriptions/000-0030303-0303/resourceGroups/30303030`. This will yield a `PolicyViolation` response with a detailed `evaluationDetails` with part of it like this (this is something you wouldn't see this detailed if you try through the Portal):

```
{
                "result": "False",
                "expressionKind": "Field",
                "expression": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/createdBy",
                "path": "properties.createdBy",
                "targetValue": [
                    "5000-0-0-0-0-0--0000"
                ],
                "operator": "In"
            }
```

As you can see, it's missing an `expressionValue`. This simply means it couldn't get the value for your expression.

An evaluation where it does find a value looks something like this :

```
 {
                "result": "True",
                "expressionKind": "Field",
                "expression": "type",
                "path": "type",
                "expressionValue": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
                "targetValue": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
                "operator": "Equals"
            },
```

`createdBy`, `updatedBy` and also properties like `createdOn` and `updatedOn` all suffer from this (i only checked on the aliasses for `roleAssignments`, other objects have similar aliasses but i didn't test these). The only scenario where these are useful is when you want to audit existing assignments. You'll notice that this will work fine, because when the assignment is actually written, it obviously has all the values.

I think the logic Microsoft handles is: only when the `createdOn` property is known, then we can assume what the `createdBy` property would be. And the `createdOn` can never be known during policy evaluation since it will never know exactly what time evaluation is done. Maybe it's flawed but this is what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a feature called "Delegate role assignments with conditions (preview)", which is exactly what you want, but with build-in functionality! Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/delegate-role-assignments-overview?tabs=template#a-more-secure-method-delegate-role-assignments-with-conditions-preview.